# Calculating number of trips without using a loop

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I am currently working on postgres and below is the question that I have.

We have a customer ID and the date when the person visited a property. Based on this I need to calculate the number of trips. Consecutive dates are considered as one trip. Eg: If a person visits on first date the trip no is first, post that he visits consecutively for three days that will counted as trip two.

Below is the input

```
ID  Date   
1   1-Jan  
1   2-Jan  
1   5-Jan  
1   1-Jul  
2   1-Jan  
2   2-Feb  
2   5-Feb  
2   6-Feb  
2   7-Feb  
2   12-Feb
```

Expected output

```
ID  Date    Trip no  
1   1-Jan   1  
1   2-Jan   1  
1   5-Jan   2  
1   1-Jul   3  
2   1-Jan   1  
2   2-Feb   2  
2   5-Feb   3  
2   6-Feb   3  
2   7-Feb   3  
2   12-Feb  4
```

---

I am able to implement successfully using loop but its running very slow given the volume of the data.

Can you please suggest a workaround where we can not use loop.

Comment: What is datatype of column `Date`?

Comment: please post your loop code

Comment: The date is date format

Answer (score 6):

Subtract a sequence from the dates -- these will be constant for a particular trip.  Then you can use `dense_rank()` for the numbering:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by id order by grp) as trip_num
from (select t.*,
             (date - row_number() over (partition by id order by date) * interval '1 day'
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! This worked and its really helpful